# Accessing Different Image Source Folder Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello I'm learning to use CodeIgniter 3. I'm having trouble accessing image sources from a different CodeIgniter Applications folder. In this case I have a domain and a sub-domain. For example, my domain name is (**a.com**), and subdomain (**sub.a.com**)

**1. (sub.a.com)** it has a feature to upload images that will be stored in a folder (*assets/images*):

- *application*
- *assets* (*images*)
- *system*

**2. (a.com)**, have a folder structure like this:

- *application*
- *system*

On (**sub.a.com**), I use a query like this to display the images:

```html
<?php foreach ($images as $img) { ?>
  <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/').$img->image;?>">
<?php } ?>
```

The problem is, is it possible (**a.com**) to access the images in the (***sub.a.com**/assets/images*) folder, by using 1 database (tb_images)?

Because I was required to have 2 different CodeIgniter folders. Can you help me, by providing a reference? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are they both on the same server?

Comment: Does server permissions allows it? For images to show up in HTML they must be URL accessible, so it's different than accessing files via PHP

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran, yes. On the same server. Is it possible to access the folder?

Comment: As @Justinas said, if URL is accessible.  You can access image with full URL path i.e. https://sub.a.com/assets/images/yourimage.jpg.

To use subdomain URL in main domain. You can define global variable to assign your sub domain to use it any where in main / primary domain

Comment: @Justinas. Yes, it is true. But when accessing the folder, it doesn't display any images

Comment: @CaPsLoCk. But (sub.a.com) accesses tb_images, in (a.com). The problem is taking pictures at (sub.a.com/assets/images).$img->image

Comment: Pls consider subdomain path as external image URL path. As you said in your question, you have same database for both. So, @Akhilesh B Chandran answer is same, what we discussed in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this in you **a.com** application:

```
<?php foreach ($images as $img) { ?>
  <img src="https://sub.a.com/assets/images/<?php echo $img->image; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

That is, rather than using the `base_url()`, use the full URL there. Or you can define the `https://sub.a.com/assets/images/` in a global variable or create a helper function that appends this part, when you echo the image url